# How to deal Auth::attempt() function with binary value in Laravel and MSSQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, authentication

How to work with Auth::attempt Laravel and binary(13) type data in MSSQL Database? I've tried write a code convertStringToBinary() in PHP perhaps it will convert the same value with CONVERT(binary, id) in SQL Query but the result still didn't match and maybe I write a wrong code or do not know. Oke here my function login(Request $request) code in LoginController

```php
$request->validate([
    'id' => 'required|min:4|max:11',
    'password' => 'required|min:3|max:16'
]);

try {
    if (Auth::attempt(['id' => $request->id, 'password' => $request->password])) {
        return to_route('dashboard');
    } else {
        return to_route('login')->with('error', 'Oppss!! Username and password is wrong');
    }
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    dd($e);
}
```

When I try to run that code it's always return this code `php return to_route('login')->with('error', 'Oppss!! Username and password is wrong');`

FYI, The scheme of tbl_rfaccount by default id, password column is binary(13) type data, so when I change that type, I cannot login into RF Launcher. I try to build a website gaming (RF Online)

I've tried to change my code, something like this

```php
$request->validate([
    'id' => 'required|min:4|max:11',
    'password' => 'required|min:3|max:16'
]);

// get data from table tbl_rfaccount
$result = DB::selectOne('SELECT id, password FROM dbo.tbl_rfaccount WHERE id = CONVERT(varchar, ?)', [$request->id]);

// converted the result into a string
$idString = str_replace("\x00", "", trim($result->id));
$passString = str_replace("\x00", "", trim($result->password));

try {
    // try to match that values
    if ($request->id == $idString && $request->password == $passString) {
        
        // and try Auth::attempt function with values are same in tbl_rfaccount
        if (Auth::attempt(['id' => $result->id, 'password' => $result->password])) {
            return to_route('dashboard');
        } else {
            return to_route('login')->with('error', 'Login failed, please try again');
        }
    } else {
        return to_route('login')->with('error', 'Oppss!! Username and password is wrong');
    }
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    dd($e);
}
```

When I try to run that code it's always return this code `php return to_route('login')->with('error', 'Login failed, please try again');`

I added dd() function for debug,

```php
dd([
    $request->id,                // from request
    $result->id,                 // from DB::select()
    $idString,                   // from str_replace("\x00", "", trim($result->id))
    $request->password,          // from request
    $result->password,           // from DB::select()
    $passString                  // from str_replace("\x00", "", trim($result->id))
]);
```

here the result

```php
array:6 [▼ // app\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php:62
  0 => "test6"
  1 => "t\x00e\x00s\x00t\x006\x00\x00\x00\x00"
  2 => "test6"
  3 => "123"
  4 => "1\x002\x003\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
  5 => "123"
]
```

and here the table from MSSQL
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vO427.png)

Comment: What are you try to achieve specifically?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Laravel's Auth:attempt, but if it uses bcrypt then a `binary(13)` column is far too small to store bcrypt hashes - the salt alone is 22 characters.

Comment: @JesusErwinSuarez I try to build game cp for my own RF Offline project, like https://nitrocp.com/

Comment: Yeah it's hard to custom Auth::attempt. I've been try to use manual auth, with condition like this  ($request->id == $idString && $request->password == $passString) then if matches it's return to dashboard, but always redirect to login again